# In coldfusion, cfspreadsheet Hidden tabs do not remain hidden

Tags: coldfusion, cfspreadsheet

I am trying to hide a tab of a spreadsheet in CF 9, but the tab does not remain hidden.
I am working with the hidden data, then saving the worbook using CF functions.

I added the following before using spreadsheetsave:

```
sheetIndex = sObj.SHEETNUMBER - 1 ; // -1 its java 0 indexed ...vs cf 1 indexed 
poiObj= sObj.getWorkBook();
poiObj.setSheetHidden(javacast("int",sheetIndex), javacast("boolean", true));
```

Is this a bug or something I can workaround? Perhaps I need to save from script directly?

Comment: There is no function named `spreadsheetsave`. I assume you mean [SpreadSheetWrite](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSe9cbe5cf462523a0-7b585809122c5a12c54-7fff.html)?

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me, so I suspect there is something else going on in the code that we cannot see. You should post an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Without knowing more, perhaps you are trying to hide the only sheet in the workbook? At least one sheet in the workbook must always be visible.

```
<cfscript>
    sheet = SpreadSheetNew("First Sheet");
    SpreadSheetCreateSheet(sheet, "Second Sheet");
    SpreadSheetCreateSheet(sheet, "Third Sheet");

    // note: this is an undocumented function
    wb = sheet.getWorkBook();
    sheetIndex = wb.getSheetIndex("Second Sheet"); 
    wb.setSheetHidden( javacast("int", sheetIndex), javacast("boolean", true));
    SpreadSheetWrite(sheet, "c:\path\someFile.xls", true);
</cfscript>
```

Comment: Thank you, this does work in my environment, did add true to first spreadsheetnew to push to xml format, that worked too. Will try again, distracted with work priorities. (Thanks for your help today.) Back to the fires.

Comment: On investigation, I was attempting to hide the current sheet. By changing the 'active sheet', the desired sheet can be hidden. (It does not automagically go to another sheet when you hide the current one.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. Can you write that up as an "answer"? (That is allowed). It will make it easier for others to find, plus people can vote on it as well.

Comment: To better help the next guy, can you adjust the simple example above to show what you did? :) Then I can delete this response and up vote yours.

Answer (score 0):

On investigation, I was attempting to hide the current sheet. By changing the 'active sheet' to any other sheet, the sheet desired to be hidden, can be hidden.

(It does not auto-magically go to another sheet when you (try to) hide the current one. – just ends up doing nothing.  )